# How do i properly set multiple projects build with build server

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, tfsbuild, sql-server-data-tools

We have a wpf solution, wherein we have all the UI BLL and DAL projects. the problem started when we tried to include our SQLProject into the solution and tried to publish it with the build server.

Having a quick look on internet I figured out that we need to have an argument like this -

```
/t:Build /t:Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath=DatabaseSQL07.publish.xml
```

so that build server knows what to build, this mentioned publish file is also the default file.

Now when gated build happens it cries out saying ..

```
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch. 

TF270015: 'MSBuild.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'.
```

I here do not understand why is not having parallel build an issue, why cant we have projects building sequentially ? can I set it to not look for /m because when I set parameters to include '/m'  it complaints about -

```
Could not copy the file "C:\....\DEV\Binaries\ProjUI.exe.manifest" because it was not found.
```

It should have been pretty simple imo but I guess I am missing something.

Any suggestions would be worth appreciation ..

Comment: 'Building the projects in this solution one at a time.' is probably just a message, and is not related to the unexpected exit code from MsBuild.

Comment: its definitely being shown as error here --  2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
 Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.          TF270015: 'MSBuild.exe' returned an unexpected exit code. Expected '0'; actual '1'.

Comment: What about using the '/m:1' switch to explicitly state you want it to build synchronously?

Comment: its still the same result, asks me to add /m switch